# How to read image from database(sqlite Django) not local file?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, opencv, django-models

- OpenCV => 3.4,  Operating System / Platform => Ubuntu18.4,  Compiler
  => Pycharm2018,  Django => 2.1.2

I am trying to get an image from a database and encode the image for face recognition.

**Model**

```
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    imagefile = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.imagefile)
```

**Read Image**

```
from .models import Image
import cv2

lastimage = Image.objects.last()
imagefile = lastimage.imagefile
image = cv2.imread(imagefile)
cv2.imshow('image',image)
```

**Error**
*Get this error*

> Exception Type:   TypeError
>
> Exception Value:   bad argument type for built-in operation

Comment: If you want to decode from a memory buffer instead of file, you're looking for `cv2.imdecode`.

Comment: A `FileField` stores a path to a file, relative to your `MEDIA_ROOT`. It looks to me like you'll want to get the full path if you want to be able to read the file.

Comment: The image is not stored in the database, only a string representing the path to the image is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my method when create a AI web project :

np.ndarray <=( cv2.imencode| cv2.imdecode) =>  buff <==> base64

Comment: I solve this problem. Thanks
`    image = np.asarray(bytearray(imagefile.read()), dtype="uint8")

    image_encode = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
`